# Android GoogleMaps not working on some devices shows java.lang.SecurityException: need INSTALL_LOCATION_PROVIDER permission

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I was trying to make a Map application with `GoogleMap` to get coordinate of location and Reverse Geocoding. I'd tried to run it in Lenovo A7000plus, it ran properly without any trouble.

Somehow, I test my application to some Xiaomi with same Android Marshmallow, the Maps not working at all. Only error reports like this :

```
07-28 14:04:01.144 19465-19465/? E/NetworkLocationProvider: Exception
                                                            java.lang.SecurityException: need INSTALL_LOCATION_PROVIDER permission, or UID of a currently bound location provider
                                                                at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
                                                                at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
                                                                at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.reportLocation(ILocationManager.java:1281)
                                                                at com.android.location.provider.LocationProviderBase.reportLocation(LocationProviderBase.java:136)
                                                                at com.amap.android.location.v.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
07-28 14:04:01.164 19465-19465/? E/NetworkLocationProvider: Exception
                                                            java.lang.SecurityException: need INSTALL_LOCATION_PROVIDER permission, or UID of a currently bound location provider
                                                                at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
                                                                at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
                                                                at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.reportLocation(ILocationManager.java:1281)
                                                                at com.android.location.provider.LocationProviderBase.reportLocation(LocationProviderBase.java:136)
                                                                at com.amap.android.location.v.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
```

Also, here's my implemented Manifest

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />

<permission
    android:name="com.myapps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.myapps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
```

Could you help me how to solve this issue ?

**EDIT : ** I've put that Runtime Permission on my code, since all phone I used including Lenovo A7000 are Marshmallow. But somehow it won't work in Xiaomi phone with same version of Android

Answer (score 1):

You must ask runtime permission in order to access the location data. Since the release of Android 6.0, the users grant permissions to the app at runtime. This [link](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) explains about the runtime permission.

Answer (score 1):

From API 23 you need to request for dangerous permissions at runtime check this link how to request dangerous at runtime https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html or in your build.gradle file change your target SDK level to 22

Answer (score 0):

Per the docs, [`INSTALL_LOCATION_PROVIDER`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INSTALL_LOCATION_PROVIDER) is

> Not for use by third-party applications.