# Android studio java.lang.SecurityException: need INSTALL_LOCATION_PROVIDER permission

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gps, location

I am working on android studio. I am getting live GPS coordinates on a mobile app. On every mobile device, the coordinates are generated but a single mobile is not working and giving `zero(0)` coordinates having android version `9`. Below is my code

```
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
 public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}
```

**Gradle**

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 33
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.wrflhr.wrfnanbookings"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 33
    versionCode 3
    versionName "3.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        debuggable false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
```

How to get rid of this issue? I have been stuck for so many days
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Might be because of Permission. Add permission check

Comment: I did allow it when asked for permission

Comment: there is a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45367436/9394700

Comment: or might be the vendor issue? with location provider

Comment: `How to get rid of this issue?` Unclear which issue you have. I see no problem description. "not working" what does it mean?

Comment: @blackapps the coordinates are in `0.0`

Comment: @Moeez please check if other apps like maps is getting location in that device, may be the hardware issue it is.

Comment: @AkshayPaliwal the map is working perfectly alright i have checked it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`android.permission.INSTALL_LOCATION_PROVIDER` permission falls under the system or signed permissions which means only system applications can request this permission.

> Only OEMs are allowed to install a new location provider. A third-party developer cannot grant to his/her application the permission required to install a new location provider (android.permission.INSTALL_LOCATION_PROVIDER). [Read Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12730719/16177121)

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INSTALL_LOCATION_PROVIDER)

> Allows an application to install a location provider into the Location Manager.
>
> Not for use by third-party applications.
>
> Constant Value: "android.permission.INSTALL_LOCATION_PROVIDER"

In order to request this permission you have to sign your app as a system app. [See How](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37586255/16177121)

In order to install a new location provider either you have to root your android device or you have to develop a whole new firmware. [Read Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3477237/16177121)